# Image won't load from web

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to display an image from a random URL which I get from another site, but the image doesn't display when run, this is the code I tried (imageView is declared above onCreate and parse is called in onCreate).

```
void parse(String url){
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(cat.this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                String message;
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try{
                        message=response.getString("url");
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(message));
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
                }
            }, error -> {
                error.printStackTrace();
                requestQueue.stop();
            });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    requestQueue.stop();
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String src) {
    try {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

this is the result of this code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use loading image services like glide,fresco,picasso

thousand time easier and faster than this way